# Postgresql - CSV Import Truncates

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm trying to import a .csv file with 131k+ rows into PostgreSQL DB.
Only 65535 rows get imported. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

```
COPY tablename (field names...)
FROM 'my CSV File Path'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: The file has rows that wrap  and so you  are counting them twice e.g. 131,000 / 2 = 65,500.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the table you are importing to has a auto-incrementing identifier which is an unsigned integer. The maximum number of possible values for that data type is 65,535. It's possible that Postgres imports the data until it gets to that point, and then just gives up.

If you have an identifier, try making it an unsigned integer (or larger size), instead of an unsigned smallint.

Comment: No that is not correct as `COPY` is an all or none operation. If an error was thrown nothing would be entered. Also Postgres does not have unsigned int of any size.

Comment: Good points. If that's the case, then my theory isn't right, but the 65,535 isn't random. It suggests something is limited by a 2 byte integer range. Although it could be that the file was generated with this range, and has an extra line break as you suggested.

Comment: `COPY` is all or none, if anything threw an error due to smallint overrun the entire statement would fail and nothing would be entered. You either get all the rows or none of them. 65,535 x 2 = 131,270, which to me is 131K+